# I created a function that is returning nothing?

Tags: php

```
$newid = 100;
$cin = 0;
function new_id() {
    $cin++;
    if ($cin >= 3) {
        $cin = 0;
        $newid++;
    }
    return $newid;
}
echo new_id();
```

new_id() is returning nothing. What's going on?

Comment: The effect you're observing has to do with scope.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: @mario Apparently OP isn't getting an error message. Although it might be just due to configuration differences.

Answer (score 5):

You need to learn about [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). `$newid` and `$cin` are not available to `new_id` unless you pass them as parameters (or use evil things like `global`):

Perfect example from the manual:

```
<?php
$a = 1; /* global scope */ 

function test()
{ 
    echo $a; /* reference to local scope variable */ 
} 

test();
?>
```

> This script will not produce any output because the echo statement refers to a local version of the $a variable, and it has not been assigned a value within this scope.

As for your code:

```
$newid = 100;
$cin = 0;
function new_id($newid, $cin) {
    $cin++;
    if ($cin >= 3) {
        $cin = 0;
        $newid++;
    }
    return $newid;
}
```

Comment: Good answer. Bad practice but reminds me of when you have to use global keyword to have an outside variable visible in a function.